# Where does the head section come from when github pages generates source?

Tags: github-pages

I created index.md for my GitHub pages site
with the following in index.md

```
---
title: This is my title
layout: default
---
## Welcome to GitHub Pages My Index.md
 etc
```

I am just editing the index.md directly in the GitHub editor. I have not installed Jekyll locally.

What do I change so that the generated source does not have my repository name in the title ?
 Looking at the source I have 
[image]

I have tried changing the theme.

I also tried experimented with adding a header.html to the _includes folder

This caused me to start receiving emails with subject containing "Page build failed"

Since then I have removed all the folders. I no longer get the "Page build failed" email, but I am unsure of how to proceed.

Comment: Studying https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/  I copied the default.html as described.  I think I need to change the line   <title>{{ site.title | default: site.github.repository_name }} by {{ site.github.owner_name }}</title>

Answer (score 2):

GitHub Pages silently sets default layouts using [jekyll-default-layout](https://github.com/benbalter/jekyll-default-layout), as described in [Publishing with GitHub Pages, now as easy as 1, 2, 3](https://github.com/blog/2289-publishing-with-github-pages-now-as-easy-as-1-2-3).

To avoid this, you can create your own `_layouts/default.html`, which should look something like this:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

And then apply the layout to your files:

```
---
layout: default
---

...
```

If you want to include the page title in the title tag, you can do something like this instead of the `_layouts/default.html` above:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ page.title }}</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

Which will use the title in your YAML front matter:

```
---
layout: default
title: Title
---

...
```

For more information, take a look at the Jekyll documentation:

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/home/

Answer (score 1):

The site title can be set in _config.yml

However it seems that the _layout\default.html is also required to make the setting work.

The help to set up the default.html is [here](https://help.github.com/articles/customizing-css-and-html-in-your-jekyll-theme/)
under the title "Customizing your Jekyll theme's HTML layout"

Comment: Seems I should have been reading https://github.com/pages-themes/tactile readme.md

Comment: Good catch. +1 (I woke up too late)

Answer (score 1):

**HOW IT WORKS ?**

Post content will mention name of layout file which will be in `_layout` folder. So for following post corresponding layout will be in `_layouts/default.html`

```
---
title: This is a post with default layout
layout: default
---
Some text for post
```

Typically *default.html* layout consumes files **head.html** and **header.html** inside **_includes** folder.

**ACTION**

Now you have to look at markdown of your page or post and identify its parent layout (*inside _layouts*) and from there drill-down into _includes. This will allow you to trace lines those are getting generated into output html. Also you can have your own _includes and _layouts for custom html output.

Comment: >>Typically default.html layout consumes files head.html and header.html inside _includes folder
I can't see this happening inside default.html  what would it look like?

Comment: Open default.html in layouts where you'll find inclusion of head.html and header.html using command: `{% include header.html %}` and `{% include head.html %}`. At location of commands insertions shall be done.